# Google Scholar Public Access new feature and lost citations

Tags: citations, google-scholar

Google's new "Public Access" feature invites you to upload preprints of some of your papers. These preprints are stored in Google Drive.

Today I used this feature and uploaded two preprints. Then, I realized that my total citation count decreased exactly by an amount corresponding to the citations by those two papers.

If I add up all the citations individually I still can recover my old total citation count but the right panel has a lower citation count.

Is this a bug of the new feature? has anybody experienced this?

Comment: I did what you did and lost citations as a result.  No idea what happened.  It is new, and hence, probably buggy or the additional data led to a correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same yesterday, with exactly the same effect.

The good news: One day later, the lost citations are back.